# how can I make a bookmark that installs jquery?

Tags: browser

how can I make a bookmark that installs jquery?

so that when I am in the developer console, I can call jquery functions from whatever websites i'm on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have such a bookmark (called a bookmarklet):

```js
javascript:!function(){var jq = document.createElement('script'); jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq); /*jQuery.noConflict();*/}();
```

You can update it to the latest jquery.

Comment: looks like . a bookmark that includes javascript is called a bookmarklet.. e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_A3Y3eqnzE